# Error al enviar consulta a través de parámetros con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una base de datos simple al cual estoy haciendo consultas y estoy pasando a travez de parametros el nombre de la tabla, el nombre de algun campo y un valor. El valor de la tabla si es necesaria, pero los campos y el valor pueden ser `null`.

El problema es que no puedo ver los resultados y el error que me arroja es este: `...foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null`.

Comparto el trabajo

Tabla diaria

```
| id | valor  | fecha
--------------------------
|  1 | 345.90 | 2022-09-26
|  2 | 230.32 | 2022-09-26
```

Clase data

```
class Data extends Db{

   public function getInfo($tabla, $ntabla, $valor){

    if($ntabla == null && $valor == null){

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$tabla;
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } else{

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$tabla.' WHERE '.$ntabla.' = '.$valor;
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($ntabla, $valor));
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }

}
```

Archivo respuesta.php

```
$object = new Data();

// $valores = $object->getInfo('diaria',valor,null);

$todo = $object->getInfo('diaria',null,null); // obtener todos los datos de la tabla diaria

foreach ($todo as $row) {
    echo $row[0]['tipo'];
}
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano!

Comment: Ponle un `return $result;` al final de la función

Comment: Dios mío... hace una hora que estoy lidiando con esto... siento vergüenza... soy un inútil... muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparte de que no retornas nada, hay más errores.

En el caso de que la columna y el valor no sean nulos, debes escribir la consulta como **realmente preparada**, poniendo un marcador en todos los casos, y pasando los datos en el `execute()` mediante un array asociativo.

Así no sólo va a funcionar, sino que tu forma de consultar será segura contra *inyección SQL*. Debes tener presente que no puedes usar nombres de tablas / columnas para pasarlos como datos en consultas preparadas, por lo que esto `$stmt->execute(array($ntabla, $valor));` no tendría sentido si `$ntabla` es el nombre de una columna.

Así debería funcionar en ambos casos:

```
class Data extends Db{

   public function getInfo($tabla, $ntabla, $valor){

    if($ntabla == null && $valor == null){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tabla";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } else{

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $ntabla = :valor";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(":valor"=>$valor));
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }

}
```

### PD

1. Si usas comillas dobles para tus cadenas, podrás meter variables dentro, escribiendo así un código más limpio
2. Este tipo de consultas genéricas necesitan más controles, como verificar contra una lista blanca que las tablas existen y que tienen asociadas las columnas que les estás pasando y verificar siempre eventuales errores en la consulta SQL.